# Iterate table with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a table created dynamically, and I need a button to get a list of values from this table, example:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
       <tr>  <td>Jhon    </td>  <td> 32 </td>  </tr>
       <tr>  <td>William </td>  <td> 37 </td>  </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button>Execute</button>
```

The button need to get a list, like:

```
var list = {{"Jhon"},{"William"}};
```

How could I do this?

Edit:
I try this:

```
var table = document.getElementById('tabelaDePontos');
var rowLength = table.rows.length;
for(var i=0; i<rowLength; i+=1){
    var row = table.rows[i];
    var cellLength = row.cells.length;
    for(var y=0; y<cellLength; y+=1){
      var cell = row.cells[y];
        console.log(cell);
     }
}
```

But it gives me all html code from table.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, but, I am not an expert in javascript/JQuery, I try use directly DOM, but it get all html from table...

Comment: However you should add your try to the question, so we could see you're making an effort...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need jQuery. Just use native DOM API.

```js
const $table = document.querySelector('table')

function execute () {
  const result = Array.prototype.map.call($table.rows, row => {
    return row.cells.item(0).textContent
  })
  console.log(result)
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
       <tr>  <td>Jhon    </td>  <td> 32 </td>  </tr>
       <tr>  <td>William </td>  <td> 37 </td>  </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button onclick="execute()">Execute</button>
```

Comment: There's nothing bad about it in this case. In fact using it for a single specific element on the whole page, it would be worse to do it from JavaScript. You need to maintain some ID or some class in both HTML and JS files. Like this, you just reference the function directly. Also @ZakariaAcharki I'm not your brother.

Comment: _And_ it's just demonstration purposes. It has nothing to do with the question. There are at least 5 other things which would never be exactly the same in real production code.

Comment: Good luck brother

Answer (score 3):

That could be done using the `click` event attached to the button, and the `map()` function to loop through the table rows `$('table tr')` and return the first column text after the trim to remove extra spaces like :

```
$("td:eq(0)", this).text().trim()
```

**Sample jQuery snippet:**

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var names = $('table tr').map(function() {
    return $("td:eq(0)", this).text().trim();
  }).get();

  console.log(names);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Jhon </td>
      <td> 32 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>William </td>
      <td> 37 </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button>Execute</button>
```

**Sample pure JS snippet:**

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var names = [];

  document.querySelectorAll('table tbody tr').forEach(function(row) {
    names.push(row.cells.item(0).textContent.trim());
  });

  console.log(names);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Jhon </td>
      <td> 32 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>William </td>
      <td> 37 </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button>Execute</button>
```

Comment: Isn't this what you was looking for @Lucas?